# How to hide datagridview cell value but value and image should be kept c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I want to erase datagridview cell value but need to keep the value and image. I drew that image inside cellPainting event. please check the image and tell me someone to achieve this. Thanks

[image: Please check this image]

```
  private void dgvMobileOperators_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 1)
            {
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                p.X += 24;
                // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\connect1.png";
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 64, 16);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 8 && Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) == 0)
            {
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                dgvMobileOperators[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                PointF p = e.CellBounds.Location;
                // p.X += imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
                p.X += 24;
                // string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EasySMPP\App\Images\sms.ico");
                string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\Images\\disconnect.png";
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y, 64, 16);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black, p);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the simplest way is probably to set the `ForeColor` of the `Column` to `Transparent`:

```
dgvMobileOperators.Columns[8].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;       
dgvMobileOperators.Columns[8].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Transparent;
```

This way you keep the value but invisible.

However, since you are `CellPainting` the cells anyway, why don't you simply skip the `DrawString` calls??

Answer (score 0):

Select status column two times like status1 status2 and hide the status1 column(which is having original values) , for status2 column hard code the null values, in c# write the logic(show the image) for status2 column based on status1....